# string templates not working - js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning how template strings works with es2015 but somehow the output I get is not what is expected but I don't see what I did wrong.

Can someone please give me a hand?

```
function buildUser(first, last){
    let fullName = '${first} ${last}';

    return { first, last, fullName };
}

let b = buildUser("Talyer", "Willams");
console.log(b);
```

What I get back is an object which is expected but the object returns

```
first: Talyer
last: Willams
fullName: ${first} ${last}
```

why am I getting `${first} ${last}`? Shouldn't I get something like `Talyer Willams`?

Comment: it should be a backtick not a single quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You need to be using a backtick not a single quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
let fullName = '${first} ${last}';
```

should be

```
let fullName = `${first} ${last}`;
```

Comment: ah ok! in the video it looks like just single quote, no wonder! thx a lot